# ReactJS useStyles to override text field font color of child component from parent component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to override the font color of a child text field component from it's parent component but haven't been able to do so and not sure why. I created a simple demo project at https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-waterfall-3okx4?file=/src/SearchBar.js where "fieldone" CSS class defined in "FieldOne.js" sets the font color to red and "fieldoneoverride" CSS class defined in SearchBar.js, where I'm importing the FieldOne.js child component, sets the font color to green. Hoping someone might be able to provide some insight on what I'm doing wrong as I'm a ReactJS newbie. Thanks in advance!

SearchBar.js code snippet

````
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import FieldOne from "./FieldOne";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  searchbar: {
    width: "calc(100% - 300px)",
    height: "auto",
    float: "left",
    flexGrow: "1",
    border: "1px solid #989586",
    borderRadius: "9999px",
    backgroundColor: "#fbfbf8",
    margin: "0",
    paddingLeft: "30px"
  },
  fieldoneoverride: {
    color: "green !important"
  }
}));

export default function SearchBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.searchbar}>
      <FieldOne className={classes.fieldoneoverride} />
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need declare props `className` in your `FieldOne`:

```
function BasicTextFields({ className })
```

Then, update inputProps of `TextField` in `BasicTextFields` like this

```
inputProps={{ className: `${classes.fieldone} ${className}` }}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bird-hff2i?file=/src/SearchBar.js

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Viet I just now tested your advised changes and it is working as intended. I will need to remember to do this.